# Which MongoDB scaling strategy (Sharding, Replication) is suitable for concurrent connections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, devops

Consider scenario that

- I have multiple devclouds (remote workplace for developers), they are all virtual machines running on the same bare-metal server.
- In the past, they used their own MongoDB containers running on Docker. So that number of MongoDB containers can add up to over 50 instances across devclouds.

The problem becomes apparent that while 50 instances is running at the same time, but only 5 people actually perform read/write operations against their own instances. So other 45 running instances waste the server's resources.

Should I use only one MongoDB cluster by combining a set of MongoDB instances ,for everyone so that they can connect to 1 endpoint only (via internal network) to avoid wasting resources.

I am considering the sharding strategy, but the problem is there are chances that if one node taken down (one VM shut down), is that ok for availability (redundancy)?

I am pretty new to sharding and replication, looking forward to know your solutions. Thank you

Comment: You will always want replication, otherwise a single node failure makes the service unavailable. A replica set gives you redundancy and fail-over. You need sharding only if you want to handle huge data sets. In your scenario (with 50 unrelated clients that don't share data), you could have multiple independent (non-sharded) clusters instead (each of them a replica set).

Comment: All of this brings some operational overhead with it. You may or may not need to set up proper access controls to avoid the clients stepping on each other, for example. Also makes it more difficult to scale them independently. Are you sure those idle Mongo instances are that resource-intensive? Presumably you also have other idle containers for each of these services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each developer expects to have *full control* over their database deployment, you can't combine the deployments. Otherwise one developer can delete all data in the deployment, etc.

If each developer expects to have *access to one database*, you can deploy a single replica set serving all developers and assign one database per developer (via authentication).

Sharding in MongoDB sense (a sharded cluster) is not really going to help in this scenario since an application generally uses all of the shards.  You can of course "shard manually" by setting up multiple replica sets.